# Problem with CSS in NGINX server debian 8

Tags: css, nginx

[so.. here appear the css don't working and the link with .php cause without .php don't work just got 404 not found nginx.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXh0d.png)

and my nginx config is

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/painel.site.com.br;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name painel.site.com.br www.painel.site.com.br;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

my assets is on /var/www/painel.site.com.br/assets

Comment: Unless the file is being blocked, this likely isn't an Nginx issue. It's probably an issue with your HTML or your file structure. Can you provide some more context?

Comment: it looks like your images aren't loading either

Comment: like what some more context

Comment: yes like the site just go a infinite loop and in f12 appear images and disappear and go reloading and reloading the page..

Comment: you'll need to post index.php.  sounds like your client side code has issues.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/cVCcwu8i